# extracting text using flags to focus on bold / italic font using PyMUPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, bold, pymupdf

I am trying to extract bold text elements from PDFs using PyMUPDF 1.18.14. I was hoping that this would work as I understand from the docs that `flags=4` targets bold font.

```
page = doc[1]
text = page.get_text(flags=4)
print(text)
```

But it prints out all text on the page and not just bold text.

When using the `TextPage.extractDICT() (or Page.get_text(“dict”))` like this:-

```
page.get_text("dict", flags=11)["blocks"]
```

The flag works but I am having trouble understanding what it is doing. Maybe switching between image and text blocks.

**Span**

So it seems you have to get to the `span` to be able to access flags.

```
<page>
    <text block>
        <line>
            <span>
                <char>
    <image block>
        <img>
```

[image]

So you can then do something like this, I used `flags=20` on the span tag to get the bold font.

```
page = doc[1]
blocks = page.get_text("dict", flags=11)["blocks"]
for b in blocks:  # iterate through the text blocks
    for l in b["lines"]:  # iterate through the text lines
        for s in l["spans"]:  # iterate through the text spans
            if s["flags"] == 20:  # 20 targets bold
                print(s)
```

But this seems like a long away around.

So my question is this the best way of finding bold elements or is there something I am missing?

Would be great to be able to search for bold elements using `page.search_for()`

Comment: I am looking to do something similar.  Your Q was surprisingly useful in helping me navigate the documentation.  So thanks. From what I can see there is no simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to extract bold text from pdfs and I tried your code and I found out that in some pdfs the bold text may not always have a flag value of 20, instead the flag value I found was 16. I might be confusing something as pymupdf is new to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).