# how to extract bold text , unbold text and tables from pdf in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have lots of pdf in same format (contents are different).
the pdf contains text, tables,etc.
The pdf also has bold text which I want to extract and convert it into column name and the details under the bold text, I want to extract and convert it into rows.
the pdf contains tables also.
I want to do this all-in python.
any idea?

this is what I tried so far.
no idea after that.

```
import PyPDF2
df=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("246427 postop note.pdf")
print(df.getNumPages())

str1=""""""
for i in range(0,4):
    str1+=df.getPage(i).extractText()
print(str1)
```

Comment: use `camelot.py` for tables

Comment: & for bold text, use fitz/pymupdf2 ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382847/extracting-text-using-flags-to-focus-on-bold-italic-font-using-pymupdf